# Action bar tabs - getting x, y position of a tab

Tags: android, android-actionbar

A simple scenario:

I have an application with an `ActionBar` - which contains three tabs: TAB1, TAB2 and TAB3, all are of type [Tab](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.Tab.html).

Each tab is being displayed after the corresponding button is being pressed.
The three buttons are being displayed under the Actionbar.

Is it possible to get the X, Y positions of these buttons, individually?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to know this? We might be able to give alternative solutions.

Comment: @Warpzit I want to dynamically add Views that overlays each tab

Comment: But why use the tabs if you overlay them? Can you be a little more specific?